# MySQL - How to count unique instances of a value in relation to another column's value

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with the following columns and values:
[image]

I need to count how many times a value is within the "pickup_customer_ref" column, however I don't want to count the value twice if it is within the same "trip_id" value.

For example, the value "254" appears in "pickup_customer_ref" 4 times, though I would only want this to count as 1 as they are all for "trip_id" value "73919".

I've been trying the normal COUNT function, which I was able to see was not giving me what I was looking for. Additionally, I've tried the WITH ROLLUP, though that is also not counting how I need it to.

Comment: Please share what is your expected result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. I assume you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(count_per_trip) FROM (
    SELECT trip_id, COUNT(DISTINCT pickup_customer_ref) AS count_per_trip
    FROM your_table
    WHERE pickup_customer_ref = 254
    GROUP BY trip_id
) fancy_subquery_alias
```

Comment: Can be modified to work for the whole table if you leave off the where + condition in the inner select